# Entering BIOS via HP iLo2 remote console

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, bios, ilo

I want to enter BIOS remotely via HP iLo2 remote console. However, I tried to press F8,F10,Esc-8 and Esc-10. None of them works. Could someone teach me how to do so? Thank you.

Regards,
yuwen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Midway through the POST process, you will see a prompt to press `F9` to enter the system's ROM Setup Utility (BIOS screen). The machine will also emit a double-beep at the end of the POST phase, giving another 2-3 second opportunity to press `F9` before the system boots the operating system. Either way, it's `F9`.